# Opinions and facts on multiplexer select in implemented VHDL code.

Tags: vhdl

Ok, So in my digital design class last year we were told repeatedly how the compiler would realize or produce the same structure when given many different codes that did the same thing structurally. Now in my computer organization class this year I have came upon a situation and would like to gauge others opinion and knowledge.

As I understand a multiplexer to work you get x number of inputs and depending on a selector signal/s you output one of those inputs. I under stand that for say 8 inputs you want N number of selector bits so that 2^N=8.

My big question is, is there any difference or advantage of having the selector be say

```
entity myMultiplexer is
    Port ( S0 : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(0 to 1);

           Sum : in  STD_LOGIC;

           myAnd : in  STD_LOGIC;
           myOr : in  STD_LOGIC;
           OpOut : out  STD_LOGIC);

end myMultiplexer;
```

Where S0 is the selector as opposed to haveing the selector be like this

```
entity myMultiplexer is
    Port ( 
       S0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
       S1 : in STD_LOGIC;

       Sum : in  STD_LOGIC;

       myAnd : in  STD_LOGIC;
       myOr : in  STD_LOGIC;
       OpOut : out  STD_LOGIC);
```

end myMultiplexer;

So in the first one it would seem to me that the signal or electrical current would be coming in on the same wire where as with the second one you could have the source come from 2 separate things. Maybe also, i was just thinking; You could take 2 separate inputs and construct a signal telling one that it is vector bit 1 and the other it is vector bit 0 and then send that to the mux S0.

Anyones perspective on this would be appreciated.

Comment: -1 Don't ask for opinions. 
Have you tried to synthesize your two code fragments? Facts come from experiments!

Answer (score 1):

No difference.  The first one defines a single `signal` with two bits in it.  In the terms of your question, this is still two "wires".

You first style is more conventional (as I see it) - as it is easier to extend to more bits if required.